# Eclipse Error occurred during initialization of VM google app engine

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

Just did a fresh install of Eclips mars.2 and installed the google app engine plug in.

Imported an existing maven project, and trying to run it on the "Google App Engine at Llocal host"

Getting this error when I run it.  I'm not even sure where to start on this, I'm just following the tutorial.

Any ideas?

Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : C:\Stuff\Programming

Comment: Weird. This just happened to me too for a different plugin. I just installed a fresh copy of Eclipse and that didn't fix the problem. I'm attempting to debug right now. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Figured out the problem on my computer. The Eclipse Optimizer plugin was causing a problem. For whatever reason, Eclipse was passing -javaagent:I:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\com.zeroturnaround.eclipse.optimizer.plugin_1.0.9/agent/eclipse-optimizer-agent.jar as an argument to the plugin I was trying to run. I went to project > Run As > Run Configurations and removed the previous line from the VM arguments. It fixed the problem.